# How can you run two instances of Nginx on the same machine without Docker?

Tags: linux, nginx

I've been searching for how to install two instances of nginx on my server **without Docker/containerization**, but I've found little results. How can this be done?

Possible use cases:

- You have two applications and you don't want one to take down both if one crashes. (This is my scenario.)
- You want to give an end user control of the nginx config and process/service. Since the processes are isolated from each another, they can be stopped/started & configured independently.

Comment: Edit the question to explain the actual problem you are trying to solve (why you need 2 instances of nginx running). There is probably a better solution (e.g. configuring virtual hosts or multiple `server` instances to listen on different interfaces/ports...

Comment: @hardillb Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem using Debian Bullseye, but the steps should be similar for other Linux flavors.

- Find the nginx service file: `find / -iname "nginx.service" -type f -ls`
- Copy the service file to `/etc/systemd/system`. Here is the command for my scenario: `cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service /etc/systemd/system/nginx2.service` (the filename becomes the name of the service, so choose carefully)
- Copy the nginx config to another folder: `cp -rp /etc/nginx /etc/nginx2`
- Edit the nginx2 service file: `nano /etc/systemd/system/nginx2.service`. Change these lines:

  ```
   [Service]
   PIDFile=/run/nginx2.pid
   ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx2/nginx.conf -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx2/nginx.conf -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
   ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx2/nginx.conf -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
   ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx2.pid
  ```
- Edit the nginx config file: `nano /etc/nginx2/nginx.conf`. Change these lines:

  ```
   pid /run/nginx2.pid;
   include /etc/nginx2/modules-enabled/*.conf;

   http {

           include /etc/nginx2/mime.types;

           access_log /var/log/nginx/access2.log;
           error_log /var/log/nginx/error2.log;

           include /etc/nginx2/conf.d/*.conf;
           include /etc/nginx2/sites-enabled/*;
   }
  ```
- Delete the symbolic link for the default site, as it points to the original nginx instance's folder: `rm /etc/nginx2/sites-enabled/default`. ( To re-create, `ln -s /etc/nginx2/sites-available/default /etc/nginx2/sites-enabled/default`.)
- You cannot have two nginx instances listening on the same port & IP address (unless you're doing port sharding, which is an advanced topic...), so you must change the port(s) to not conflict with the first instance.
- Inform systemd of the new service: `systemctl daemon-reload`
- Enable the new service: `systemctl start nginx2`
- Enjoy!